# How can I set the color for subsequent plot commands?

Tags: matplotlib

I have to issue many plot commands to create a picture. As in the following example:

```
color="C0-"
plt.plot([1,5,4], color)
plt.plot([3,7,8], color)
```

To simplify code I would prefer something like:

```
plt.set_color("C0-") # ERROR
plt.plot([1,5,4])
plt.plot([3,7,8])
```

Is this possible?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If no color argument is given, the color of the plots is determined by the color cycle in use. You may change the color cycle at runtime to only have one single color, which effectively makes all subsequent plots that same color.

```
plt.gca().set_prop_cycle('color', ["blue"])
```

To get the first color of the current color cycle you may use

```
c0 = plt.rcParams["axes.prop_cycle"].by_key()["color"][0]
plt.gca().set_prop_cycle('color', [c0])
```

Comment: Updated the answer. Hope this is what you want.